# Programmatically edit update data in datalist giving error

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, datalist

i got this error when i tried to update data in datalist. these are the code i used to edit, update and delete data from the datalist. the delete is working but the update is not working as i change something to the previous data by edit. when i click on the update button the error comes "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

```
   Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    bindDataList()
End Sub

Protected Sub DataList1_CancelCommand(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As DataListCommandEventArgs)
    DataList1.EditItemIndex = -1
    bindDataList()
End Sub
Protected Sub DataList1_DeleteCommand(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As DataListCommandEventArgs)
    con.Open()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("delete from tblEmployee ", con)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
    DataList1.EditItemIndex = -1
    bindDataList()
End Sub
Protected Sub DataList1_UpdateCommand(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As DataListCommandEventArgs)
    con.Open()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
    cmd = New SqlCommand("update tblEmployee set Name=@Name", con)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DirectCast(DataList1.Controls(0).FindControl("txtEmployeeName"), TextBox).Text
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
    DataList1.EditItemIndex = -1
    bindDataList()


End Sub
Protected Sub DataList1_EditCommand(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As DataListCommandEventArgs)
    DataList1.EditItemIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex
    bindDataList()
End Sub

Sub bindDataList()
    Dim mycommand As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblEmployee where id= '5'", con)
    con.Open()
    DataList1.DataSource = mycommand.ExecuteReader
    DataList1.DataBind()
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

And the datalist design is here .

```
  <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" OnCancelCommand="Datalist1_CancelCommand" OnDeleteCommand="Datalist1_DeleteCommand" OnEditCommand="Datalist1_EditCommand" OnUpdateCommand="Datalist1_UpdateCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <div style="text-align:center">
    <table>
    <tr><td style="width:200px; height:25px" align="left">
    <asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.Dataitem, "Name")%>'></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td style="width:50px; height:25px">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit">Edit</asp:LinkButton></td>
    <td style="width:50px; height:25px">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete">Delete</asp:LinkButton></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td style="width:200px; height:25px" align="left">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmployeeName" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.Dataitem, "Name")%>'></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td style="width:50px; height:25px" align="left">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="Update">Update</asp:LinkButton>
    </td>
    <td style="width:50px; height:25px" align="left">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel">Cancel</asp:LinkButton>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <HeaderTemplate>
    <table style="width:300px">
    <tr><td style="width:200px; height:25px" align="left">
    <strong>Employee Name</strong>
    </td>
    <td style="width:200px; height:25px"></td>
            <td style="width:200px; height:25px"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

i think the problem is in somewhere at the update command. here the first two line of stack trace
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   ASP.default_aspx.DataList1_UpdateCommand(Object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
. i am not able to catch where i went wrong . plz help me

Answer (score 0):

Put this    `bindDataList()` in between `If Not IsPostBack Then  ... End If`  to prevent refreshing the grid on every postback. This will cause problem when you are updating.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
   If Not IsPostBack Then
      bindDataList()
   End If
End Sub
```